# Apple Pencil Scribble on input field crashes my Cordova app?

Tags: xcode, cordova, ipad, apple-pencil

When 'Scribble' is enabled in the Apple Pencil Settings, tapping on an input or textarea field in my Cordova app causes it to Terminate with this error:

`*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[DOMRange asDomRange]: unrecognized selector sent to instance`

How can I use Scribble in my text fields?

Comment: I would open this as an issue on cordova-ios's github

Comment: Thanks @Eric! I've done so: https://github.com/apache/cordova-ios/issues/1243. I'm not much of an obj-c guy. Do you think there would be a way to bridge UIPencilInteraction to a Cordova touch event?